# Why can we have only one constructor with @Inject annotation?

Tags: java, cdi, guice, jsr330

I know the above is mandated by the spec but would like to understand why? What will be the problem(s) if multiple constructors in a class are allowed to have @Inject annotation. I am talking about JSR 330.

P.S: I know CDI spec(ie JSR 299) leverages JSR 330's @Inject. So I am adding that tag in the question as well. Feel free to remove if it doesn't apply to CDI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If multiple constructors are annotated with `@Inject`, there will be ambiguity for the container to decide which to use to instantiate the type.

Which would you choose

```
@Inject
public Foo (Bar bar) {}
```

or

```
@Inject 
public Foo (Zoom zoom) {}
```

if there is absolutely no relation between `Bar` and `Zoom`.

Comment: I want to understand the reason for ambiguity.

Comment: Which is an "ambiguity" limit of the IoC container/spec, not a general limit. IoC containers like AutoFac (and Windsor, IIRC) have the ability to select best-match.

Comment: @Geek I like to make the parallel with ambiguity with method overloading.

Comment: @user2864740 Spring also has that ability, but only when no constructors are annotated. But these are conventions. They may not always apply. In that case, you annotate a single constructor.

Comment: hk2 gives the users the ability to choose which constructor (or methods or fields) are to be injected into with a ClassAnalyzer